# How to pass parameter in window.open method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method in JavaScript:

```
var string1 = "testing";
var date = "10/10/2012";

var win = window.open(BuildUrl(("report", "report"), "myreports",  
           "toolbar=0,statusbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,location=0");

function BuildUrl(controllerName, actionName) {        
    var TimeStamp = Number(new Date()); 
    var win = window.location;
    return win.protocol + "//" + win.host + "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName + '?_=' + TimeStamp ;  
}
```

Method in C# controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult report()
{               
    return View();
}
```

Now I need to pass parameters like name and date when the URL is accessed to the C# method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Append the parameters to the URL in the following format:

```
<url>?param1=value1&param2=value...
```

If you need to pass an array of values then use the same name for the parameter

```
<url>?arr=value1&arr=value2...
```

So your URL would look like

domain.com/Controller/Report?name=xyz&date=20

---

Update:

To receive them in the Action, declare the parameters being passed to the Action.

```
public ActionResult Report(string name, DateTime date)
{
  ...
}
```

Read up on [Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: how to receive them in c# function?

Comment: If we have more than two parameters also, we have to pass using & as delimiter right?

Comment: Yup, start with `?` and add parameters using `&`.

Comment: But if i do so, its throwing syntax error, do we need to declare param1, param2 as var variables?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, please update the question with the code.

Comment: No, its like i have a date value in jquery var variable, and a string in one variable.. i just need to pass them, i updated please respond

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29099/discussion-between-vimal-stan-and-lll)

Comment: Here chat will not work :(, please add comment here or modify the code which you have given in ans please

Answer (score 3):

I found a better way to pass parameters to the popup window and even to retrieve parameters from it :

**In the main page :**

```
var popupwindow;
var sharedObject = {};

function openPopupWindow()
{
   // Define the datas you want to pass
   sharedObject.var1 = 
   sharedObject.var2 = 
   ...

   // Open the popup window
   window.open(URL_OF_POPUP_WINDOW, NAME_OF_POPUP_WINDOW, POPUP_WINDOW_STYLE_PROPERTIES);
   if (window.focus) { popupwindow.focus(); }
}

function closePopupWindow()
{
    popupwindow.close();

    // Retrieve the datas from the popup window
    = sharedObject.var1;
    = sharedObject.var2;
    ...
}
```

**In the popup window :**

```
var sharedObject = window.opener.sharedObject;

// function you have to to call to close the popup window
function myclose()
{
    //Define the parameters you want to pass to the main calling window
    sharedObject.var1 = 
    sharedObject.var2 = 
    ...
    window.opener.closePopupWindow();
}
```

That's it !

And this is very convenient because:

- You have not to set parameters in the URL of the popup window.
- No form to define
- You can use illimited parameters even objects.
- Bi-directionnal : you can pass parameters AND, if you want you, can retreive new parameters.
- Very easy to implement.

Have Fun!

Comment: You can also pass data by setting values in the window object returned by window.open.